# How to call .map() on a list of pairs in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to call `map()` on a list of pairs, but I get a type mismatch error.

For example, suppose I want to map a List of pairs of Int to a list of their sums:

```
scala> val ll=List((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
ll: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

scala> ll.map((x:Int,y:Int)=>x+y)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
              ll.map((x:Int,y:Int)=>x+y)
                                  ^
```

By the way, when trying to run foreach() I get a very similar error:

```
scala> ll.foreach((x:Int,y:Int)=>println(x,y))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Unit
 required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
              ll.foreach((x:Int,y:Int)=>println(x,y))
                                  ^
```

What does the `?` sign stand for? What am I missing here?

Comment: I get a different error if I just use `(x,y) => x+y` Why is that? `<console>:17: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
              c.map((x,y) => x+y)`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html) to get the elements of the pair.

```
ll.map{ case (x:Int,y:Int) => x + y }
```

You don't even need to specify the types:

```
ll.map{ case (x, y) => x + y }
```

The same works with `foreach` of course.

The error message tells you that the compiler expected to find a function of *one* parameter (a pair of ints) to any type (the question mark) and instead found a function of *two* parameters, both ints.

Comment: ~6 years after, still no less verbose way to achieve that (regular parenthesis and no 'case' keyword)?

Answer (score 20):

You can use:

```
ll.map(x => x._1 + x._2)
```

where `x` stands for the tuple itself, or

```
ll.map(x:(Int,Int) => x._1 + x._2)
```

if you want to declare the types explicitly.

Comment: Whilst true; I think this is bad style; we should use `case (x, y)` at all times

Comment: Can you add a rationale ? It seems to me we know we have a tuple and so derefencing it as such isn't unreasonable ? The case 'unpacks' the tuple and you may not want that in all cases

Comment: Looking at the scala -print output of both ways, it seems both essentially do the same thing (both perform an asInstanceOf check, box and unbox), and I think the case form is more aesthetically pleasing - I wish I had realised this was possible before now!

Comment: I'm confused, because the case() variant is subject to MatchError. e.g. List(1,(2,3)).map{ case(x:Int,y:Int) => x+y } will blow up at runtime. Whereas the tuple variant above is statically checked. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: No - the compiler can still check correctness and will disallow if the type you are mapping over is not a tuple. Try `List(1, 2, 3, 4) map { case (x, y) => x + y }`. Maybe the downvote is a bit harsh but I feel very strongly that we should *never* use this form because the `case` form allows for descriptive names

Comment: Not worried about downvoted but rather what's going on. I see your example is caught at compile time. But isn't my example with List(1,(2,3)) only caught at runtime since it generates a MatchError ?

Comment: OK, good point; in which case use `collect` rather than `map`. Using `case` does not compile if you don't add in the type-ascriptions (i.e. `List(1, (2, 3)) map { case (x, y) => x + y }`). It's never an issue really as I'd never add the unnecessary ascriptions and I never have a collection which contains tuples and non-tuples

Comment: As you are worried about what's going on, I believe Marvin Gaye has the answer you are looking for

Comment: I don't think sexual healing will address my type-inference concerns

Comment: You're in luck then; it's not on that album :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can *tuple* a function, which means going from one that takes N args to one that takes 1 arg that is an N-tuple. The higher-order function to do this is available on the `Function` object. This results in nice syntax plus the extra type safety highlighted in the comments to Brian Agnew's answer.

```
import Function.tupled

ll map tupled(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Scala 3`, [parameter untupling](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html) has been extended, allowing such a syntax:

```
List((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)).map(_ + _)
// List(3, 7, 11)
```

where each `_` refers in order to the associated tuple part.